# SFTP a file as TAPE dataset to mainframe

Tags: sftp, mainframe

I need to SFTP a file from a server to mainframe. While transfering the file it should be in the form of TAPE dataset when recieved to the mainframe. Is that possible?

Comment: There's nothing built into the SFTP standard for tape datasets. You should check the documentation for the mainframe's SFTP support.

Comment: This is a scenario in which FTP over TLS (FTPS) works much better than SFTP. Pretty much all major FTP servers for z/OS have support for TAPE datasets using SITE commands. By contrast, the situation with SFTP is more mixed – there are implementations that do, but there are implementations that don't; and for some of those that do, you need to use a non-standard SFTP client, since unlike FTP, SFTP doesn't have a standardised SITE command mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

The z/OS provided `sftp` is based on the IBM OpenSSH implementation.  As such, it does not support MVS datasets as of z/OS 2.4.  Assuming by `TAPE` dataset you're referring to a traditional `PS` format.

> OpenSSH's sftp does not have built-in support for MVS™ data sets. However, there are alternate (indirect) ways to access MVS data sets within sftp.

The above quote from IBM's website can be accessed [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.4.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r4.foto100/sftpmvs.htm)

As @cschneid indicated, other products and offerings can provide additional capability but it is not provided with z/OS base operating system.

Comment: Thanks for the reformatting @piet.t ... I like the change in formatting to wrap the quote.  I'll remember that for next time.

Answer (score 0):

If what you mean by "in the form of TAPE dataset when recieved to the mainframe" is that the transferred data should go directly to tape rather than DASD, then it *may* be possible.

If the mainframe is running Dovetailed Technologies Co:Z SFTP server, [that product provides mechanisms](https://www.dovetail.com/docs/sftp/options.html) for allocating mainframe files in a detailed, mainframe, and shop-specific manner.